# a variadic function example which does not work for me

Tags: postgresql

On https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html there is the example:

```
create or replace function anyleast(variadic anyarray) returns anyelement as '
  select min($1[i])from generate_subscripts($1,1)s(i)
' language sql;
commit;

eric=> select anyleast('abc'::text,'def');
    anyleast
-----------
 abc
(1 row)
```

But when I do this, I get:

```
eric=> select anyleast('abc'::text,'def');
    anyleast
-----------
 {abc,def}
(1 row)
```

Comment: what you see when you do `\sf anyleast`?..

Comment: It works here. What @VaoTsun probably wants to say is that there may be another `anyleast` function in the `search_path`.

Comment: yes - exactly, or in same schema with two text arguments, eg ```create or replace function anyleast(a text,b text) returns table (a text[]) as '
  select array[a,b]
' language sql;```

Comment: Incredible! Yes, that is it! Thank you both!